# Read multipart form data with multiple files

Tags: c#, .net, forms, multipartform-data

I am passing in multipart form data to an API endpoint. The data is passed as a Model like this:

```
public class AttachmentModel
{
    public HttpFile Data { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public Attachment Attachment => new Attachment
    {
        Data = Data?.Buffer ?? new byte[0],
        Description = Description,
        FileName = Data?.FileName
    };
}
```

This works as it should, and the file parses properly. I would like to be able to upload multiple files at a time, and the multipart form that is sent seems to be correct, with several files being uploaded under `Data`:

```
------WebKitFormBoundarypABSUgXhqOWGIbhU
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Description"

------WebKitFormBoundarypABSUgXhqOWGIbhU
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Data"; filename="file1.pdf"
Content-Type: application/pdf

------WebKitFormBoundarypABSUgXhqOWGIbhU
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Data"; filename="file2.pdf"
Content-Type: application/pdf

------WebKitFormBoundarypABSUgXhqOWGIbhU--
```

On the Model however, if I change `Data` to be an `IEnumerable<HttpFile>`, it is null. How can I pass the data to receive all of the files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way that I got this to work was to edit the multipart form data so that the name each file was sent under had it's own index:

```
------WebKitFormBoundarypABSUgXhqOWGIbhU
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Description"

------WebKitFormBoundarypABSUgXhqOWGIbhU
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Data[0]"; filename="file1.pdf"
Content-Type: application/pdf

------WebKitFormBoundarypABSUgXhqOWGIbhU
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Data[1]"; filename="file2.pdf"
Content-Type: application/pdf

------WebKitFormBoundarypABSUgXhqOWGIbhU--
```

And then in the model I changed the Data to be a list of HttpFile:

`public List<HttpFile> Data { get; set; } = new List<HttpFile>();`